# Is there a word for someone whose life was possible because of another's death?

Tags: single-word-requests

Examples

1. A child who was only conceived because of the miscarriage of his or her older brother.
2. Someone who survives a gunshot because their friend took the bullet for them.

   ---

As in Example 1, the person may not have been saved by someone else, but another's death lead to their life.

Comment: something like "heir to their life" .. in one word .. interesting

Comment: An unrequited life debt, I suppose.

Comment: Sometimes you call those people "organ donor recipients" ...

Comment: Clearly a "phoenix from the flames".

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can think of is : **step into dead men's shoes**  though that may imply also taking on the role of the dead person.

> To take over the position or role of someone who has died.
>
> Derived from the proverb, "It's ill waiting for dead men's shoes."
>
> *With the economy as stagnant as it is, the only way to get a promotion these days is to step into dead men's shoes.*
>   - http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/step+into+a+dead+man%27s+shoes